# Program that finds a numbers divisor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been making my own little program that finds the divisors for an inputted number.

The way it determines if a number can be divided with another number is if the result is an integer. If its a float, it should come out negative.

This is what I've got so far:

```
# Divider

Number = input("> ")

divider = 1

while True:
    Number = int(Number)
    divider = int(divider)

    result = 0

    result = int(result)

    result = Number/divider

    if isinstance(result, int):    
        print("{} Y".format(divider))

    else:
        print("{} N".format(divider))

    divider = divider + 1

    if divider == Number + 1:
        break
```

The problem is that when I run the program and input a number like "10" which should have more than one divisor (1,2,5,10) it comes out completely negative:

```
> 10
1 N
2 N
3 N
4 N
5 N
6 N
7 N
8 N
9 N
10 N
>>>
```

I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post all relevant information as **text** in your question, not as images.

Comment: `isinstance(10/5,int) == isinstance(2.0,int) == False`

Comment: The `/` operator returns a `float` no matter what, you need to use the modulo operator `%` and check if it's equal to zero instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'm going to clean up your code:

```
Number = 15

divider = 1

while True:

    if divider == Number + 1:
        break

    Number = int(Number)
    divider = int(divider)

    result = Number/divider

    if isinstance(result, int):
        print("{} Y".format(divider))

    else:
        print("{} N".format(divider))

    divider = divider + 1
```

Now, what are they all return as negative? Simply because the `/` division returns a float (i.e. result is a float). What is the correct solution? Use the `%` modulo to check if the remainder is 0.

```
Number = 15

divider = 1

while True:

    if divider == Number + 1:
        break

    Number = int(Number)
    divider = int(divider)

    result = Number%divider

    if result == 0:
        print("{} Y".format(divider))

    else:
        print("{} N".format(divider))

    divider = divider + 1
```

Output:

```
1 Y
2 N
3 Y
4 N
5 Y
6 N
7 N
8 N
9 N
10 N
11 N
12 N
13 N
14 N
15 Y
```

Comment: thanks so much, and also sorry for my sloppy code :D

Comment: @kanukit by the way, the conversion to int for divider is not needed since it is an hard coded variable. And the conversion to int for Number should be done outside of the while loop.

Comment: @Mathieus Alright, I guess I started making sure everything was the right type when it wasn't working, but I'll keep what you said in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The division operator `/` always results in a floating number in Python 3, so the result will never be an instance of an integer.

You should instead use the modulo operator to test if the remainder is 0:

```
if number % divider == 0:
    print("{} Y".format(divider))
else:
    print("{} N".format(divider))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would solve it using modulus. If the remainder is 0 then its divisible otherwise its not. No need to have any `int` or `float` checks.

```
num = input("> ")
#Assuming the num is an integer
divisors = [] #List of divisors
for i in range(1,num):
  if num%i == 0:
    divisors.append(i)
```

Output:

```
>>[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for divisor in range(1, number//2+1):
  print("{} {}".format(divisor, "Y" if number % divisor == 0 else "N"))
```

Some additional advice:

- Don't use capitals for variable names.  It's good practice to name classes with capitals instead (and all-caps for constants).
- It is enough to walk until `number // 2` (the integer division) because between `number // 2` and `number` there cannot be any more divisors.
- DRY - don't repeat yourself (a very general rule in programming):  Use the `a if b else c` operator to avoid repeating the `print`.

Answer (score 0):

What about you just use modulo like in the following?

```
result = Number%divider

if result==0:   
    print("{} Y".format(divider))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input('Enter a number : '))
div = 1
count = 0
while True:
    if(div == num+1):
        break
    result = num%div
    if result == 0:
        print('{} -- yes'.format(div))
        count+=1
    else:
        print('{} -- No'.format(div))
    div+=1
print('Total number of divisor : ', count)
```